# WidgetProvider Intent extras sent with button click not found in onReceive

Tags: android, widget, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect when widget button is clicked but none of the `Intent` extras are showing up in the `onReceive` method.

`onReceive` gets called with every click but none of my `Intent` extras show up.

My code is below:  I only hook up the toggle button in on update so not sure if this is correct.  None of the extras show up and categories are `null` even though I set this.

**onUpdate(Context context etc):**

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
                                R.layout.my_widget);

Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProviderClass.class);
buttonIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
buttonIntent.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "buttonClick");
buttonIntent.putExtra("BUTTON",899);

PendingIntent muPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
                                        buttonIntent, 
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
buttonIntent.addCategory("buttonclick");
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ToggleImageButton, myPendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
```

**onReceive():**

```
intent.getIntExtra("BUTTON",-1);    ---> 1
intent.getCategories()   --- > null
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`.

Also, your code may have a typo: you have `muPendingIntent` instead of `myPendingIntent`.

Also also, please do not use `buttonclick` as a category. Please namespace it (e.g., `com.something.whatever.buttonclick`), or remove it, as I am not sure why you would need it.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/PairOfDice) demonstrating an app widget that, on a click, triggers an update on itself, with an extra (used to supply the app widget IDs).

Comment: I am looking for a way to see that the button was actually clicked in the onReceive.  They are still not showing up in onReceive.  its like its a different intent, without any extras?

Comment: I need a way to see that it was the button that fired because on receive gets other intents

Comment: I did try FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT  without effect, just none of the extras are showing up or any of the settings I have done.

Comment: @Androider: All I can tell you is that the code I linked to works. It is up to you to do the work to determine where your approach differs from mine.

Comment: well what you are doing is sending a custom action and can infer from that that a button was clicked.  That will work, and I am going to switch to that.  However, i still want to know why the extras are not preserved.  I will post if I find out.

Comment: Actually I do have the same problem. Extras are detached at some point. They work for the first time but then there are no extras.

Answer (score 1):

Android Apparently Does not like re-use of the name ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER and removes those parameters.  Created another ACTION just for toggle button, registered in the manifest and now the parameters show up.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the Intent that was used to create the Pending intent has any extras already in it then the new intent's extras are ignored. For example, if you follow the sample in the Android docs for building a Widget like so

```
Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
toastIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);
```

Then the line

```
toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
```

Will prevent your new intent's extras from sticking. I removed that line and my new intent worked.